# debug notice on my WordPress site

Tags: debug

How can i see notice and warning on WordPress site.

Like

Notice: undefined variable on line 29.

my client have point out these Notice while i am unable to see these notice any help please

Comment: That noctice will exactl tell you in which file the error is. You will need to follow that

Answer (score 1):

In your config.php
check for

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

If its true, you will see notices and warnings on site.

This link might be useful http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG.

Also check this error by logging in and logging out. If you are using any plugin for debugging, you will see that notice message when you are logged in.

Comment: I have solved it anyway thanks by the same method i have solved it